# What the difference between two if expression in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I define a new version of `if`:

```
(define (new-if predicate then-clause else-clause)
    (cond (predicate then-clause)
    (else else-clause)))
```

Then I use it as the following:

```
(define (sqrt-iter guess x)
  (new-if (good-enough? guess x)
  guess
  (sqrt-iter (improve guess x)
             x)))
```

I understand that since the `else-clause` passed to `new-if` in the `sqrt-iter` procedure is always evaluated, `sqrt-iter` never stops making recursive calls to itself.

But I don't understand why we don't stop when `good-enough?` returns `true` => `guess`

Comment: Because `sqrt-iter` never stops making recursive calls to itself?

Comment: But when we evaluate that `good-enough?` returns `true` why we don't stop?

Comment: In Scheme `if` is a special form, which means it does not evaluate all of it's arguments. Normal forms evaluate all of the arguments before executing the procedure. Other special forms are `define` `cond` `or` and `and`.  Before the interpreter calls `new-if` it tries to evaluate all of it's arguments, one of which is the recursive call. Hence infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `new-if` is a procedure. Procedure arguments are evaluated before being passed to the procedure. Therefore, your recursive `sqrt-iter` call is going to be evaluated fully before `new-if` is called. As Robert Harvey commented, this results in infinite recursion.

Your `new-if` needs to be a macro to function correctly. Something like:

```
(define-syntax new-if
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ predicate then-clause else-clause)
     (cond (predicate then-clause)
           (else else-clause)))))
```